# Can you manually "trigger" a callback in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run all callback methods manually inside a method. For example, I want to run all "before_destroy" methods inside my model.

Is there a way to manually trigger this? For example, something like:

```
def some_method
  # ...
  trigger(:before_destroy)
end
```

which will then run all methods that I have declared with "before_destroy :...."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're happy to run both :before and :after hooks, you can try `run_callbacks`.
From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Callbacks.html#method-i-run_callbacks):

```
run_callbacks(kind, &block)
```

Runs the callbacks for the given event.

Calls the before and around callbacks in the order they were set, yields the block (if given one), and then runs the after callbacks in reverse order.

If the callback chain was halted, returns false. Otherwise returns the result of the block, or true if no block is given.

```
run_callbacks :save do
  save
end
```

Answer (score -6):

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def destroy_method_1
  end

  def destroy_method_2
  end

  before_destroy :destroy_method_1, :destroy_method_2

  DESTROY_METHODS = [:destroy_method_1, :destroy_method_2]

  def some_method
    DESTROY_METHODS.each {|m| send(m) }
  end
end
```

Comment: @huanson Unnecessarily mean and unhelpful.